# How to scan finger print in salesforce?

Tags: visualforce

I've to create a field on contact object to store finger print.

now the question is;
How to scan finger print in salesforce.?

i've to use finger print scanner machine which is connected to computer externally.

Please guide.

Comment: salesforce does not provide any scanning services. You need integrate third party software which will scan the finger print, will create picture and insert that picture as attachment to Contact record

Comment: Hi @Amol In which format does the device save the fingerprint to your computer (if Salesforce is not present in between)?

Comment: Hi Arvind, scanner connected to computer is just scenario, its not implemented yet . so its a startup only

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce does not provide any scanning services. 
You need integrate third party software which will scan the finger print, will create picture and insert that picture as attachment to Contact record.

There are other ways can be implemented.

After getting scanned, the images will be saved some file storage.

From Salesforce, those files can be read though the batch process and inserts the attachment.

For more information refer [Saving the contents of an image or file URL as an attachment or Salesforce content](https://www.sundoginteractive.com/blog/saving-the-contents-of-an-image-or-file-url-and-saving-to-an-attachment-or)

Also you can think of exploring [File Connects](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_files_connect_share.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Third party app is not available on appexchange. so how accomplish this?

Comment: @Amol updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would use Salesforce to collect biometric credentials since Apex executes on server-side  and cannot interact directly with devices such  as fingerprint readers. I assume that you would need some kind of client-side library to be able to interact with the relevant API's that control the finger-print reader on devices such as smartphones, a little bit like the Phonegap/Cordova System works. You'd then collect that data and send it off to Salesforce to check it matches what you've got stored.

Currently, I don't think there's any client-side libraries available for biometrics that could be used for web development. I think the only libraries available will be for desktop development such as C#.

Do note that for biometric authentication to work, the device drivers will need to be installed on whatever device is trying to authenticate using biometric credentials. You will also need to keep the Username/Password combo in case biometrics can't be read for whatever reason or if a users device doesn't have biometric scanning hardware installed.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, as you already said, there are no applications in the appexchange which caters to your requirement.

But you can definitely give a shot to develop one with the help of REST API for the same (Depending on the the format of the finger print data which you get from the device).

Also, as @Sagar has pointed out, there would be requirements such as the installation of specific device drivers for biometric authentication; and for that there's definitely a need for client side library to be able to interact with the relevant API's that control the finger-print reader.

Just an additional info: [Does Salesforce have any apps for biometric (finger scan) reading integration?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009DYmIAM)

Comment: Hi Arvind, i'm agree but how to  go ahead with Rest API so that i can interface with device. also device has driver which to install on system. and our salesforce API should interact with driver. so that it can connect. how can i choose a way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything else that has been proposed above. I have a client that uses [this](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000qrQlEAI) application though.

It is an extra level of authentication for Salesforce that will require users to scan their fingerprint in order to login.

This is a paid application and I am pretty sure it only works for that initial authentication. I don't believe you can utilize it any where else in the instance. Just wanted to share it with you though.